# Binding LIST to listview with mutiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, listview

I tried using an example from [Manually insert an item into a ListView control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419536/manually-insert-an-item-into-a-listview-control) . I am able to insert an item with 2 fields, but the code keeps creating a new list view for each item.Where did I go wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace ISEMAILAPP
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string authorKey = "authors";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // If the session variable is empty, initialize an 
                // empty list as the datasource
                if (Session[authorKey] == null)
                {
                    Session[authorKey] = new List<mEvent>();
                }
                BindList();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = subject.Text;
            string m = message.Text;
            // Grab the current list from the session and add the 
            // currently selected DropDown item to it.
            List<mEvent> authors = (List<mEvent>)Session[authorKey];
            authors.Add(new mEvent(s,m));
            BindList();
        }

        private void BindList()
        {
            messagelist.DataSource = (List<mEvent>)Session[authorKey];
            messagelist.DataBind();
        }

        // Basic author object, used for databinding
        private class mEvent
        {
            public String AuthorName { get; set; }
            public String Message { get; set; }
            public mEvent(string name, string message)
            {
                AuthorName = name;
                Message = message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
    </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
   <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" EnableHistory="True" HorizontalAlign="NotSet">
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="messagelist" >

        <ItemTemplate>
                       <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <th>Subject</th>
                     <th>Message</th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="subjectline" Text='<%# Eval("AuthorName") %>' />
                </td>
                                    <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="messageline" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
   Subject: <asp:TextBox ID="subject" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
  Message:  <asp:TextBox ID="message" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting back the list into seesion after adding item

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = subject.Text;
    string m = message.Text;
    // Grab the current list from the session and add the 
    // currently selected DropDown item to it.
    List<mEvent> authors = (List<mEvent>)Session[authorKey];
    authors.Add(new mEvent(s,m));

    Session[authorKey] = authors;

    BindList();
}
```